# Reagarding Listview with Text and Image. How ot set Text is Dynamic and Image is Static

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with Text and Image. Text array contain "n" number of items and Image Array is static I have only 10 images.

My question is how can I set these 10 images for all items with out taking randomly means?

Item 1 = Image 1

Item 2 = Image 2

Item 3 = Image 3

---

### -----

---

---

Item 10 = Image 10

Item 11 = Image 1

Item 12 = Image 2

---

### --------

Like this I want to set Images

Comment: as it's a custom listview you'll have an adapter and in the getview method of the adapter you will have a parameter for position.and you can use this parameter to compare the position of arrays like if(position==1){imageview.setImageResource(imagearray[position];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a array of your image as imageArray.
Then in your custom adapter use the following line of code.

`imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position % 10]);
textView.setText(itemArray[position]);`

Answer (score 0):

as it's a custom listview you'll have an adapter and in the getview method of the adapter you will have a parameter for position.and you can use this parameter to compare the position of arrays like

```
if(position==1){
imageview.setImageResource(imagearray[position];
 textview.setText(textarray[position]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your adapter

```
   int counter=1;
```

and put this inside your getView() method

```
    imageView.setImageResource(image_array[counter]);
    textView.setText(data_array[position]);

    if(counter==10){
        counter=0;
    }
    counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setImageResource(image_array[position % 10]);
textView.setText(data_array[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modular division

`Position%10`

```
Imageview.setImageResource(imageArray[position%10]);
```

Comment: Yes use modulas for getting the reminder of current position when divided by 11 so that you can have a range from 1-10 only